# Admob Issue - Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.$PlaceholderFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, admob, google-play-services

Following the https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start tips I've experienced an issue with `inflating fragments`. Google play services lib is added in libs/ and as a project dependency, also tried with external reference to sdk. `Manifest` has added meta-data on top of `application` tag like:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

`AdFragment class` is set in main_activity view at the bottom of view..:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
...
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `AdFragment` `class` is placed in `Activity`:

```
public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

    private AdView mAdView;

    public AdFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit
        // ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device
        // ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admob, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

AdFragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

An error output is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.puzzle/com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5022)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:261)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1874)
    at com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity_.setContentView(MainActivity_.java:45)
    at com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity_.onCreate(MainActivity_.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5032)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity$AdFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    ... 23 more
```

Appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Post code of your MainActivity$AdFragment class

Comment: class AdFragment extends Fragment is placed as static in blank Activity, there is nothing more about admob's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace states `ClassCastException: com.xx.activities.MainActivity$AdFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment`. But there is no reference to this class elsewhere. The description in your Activity layout XML is `android:name="com.puzzle.activities.MainActivity$AdFragment"`. Note the difference in package.

It appears that you are actually loading another layout XML in your Activity than the one you showed us. Check your Activity's onCreate.

---

AdFragment extends from Fragment.
What is the import for Fragment?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

or

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

I suspect it is the latter and the Activity loading the Fragment extends `android.app.Activity` when it needs to extends `android.support.v4.app.FragentActivity`

Essentially you are combining support classes with non-support classes.

Comment: This package name is the same, I've unnecesarely changed those package name before posted on so..

Comment: Yea, this was one of two issues that have solved the issue. Please add to your solution also mention to check If there is proper google play services version set to sign your answer as sollution ;)

Comment: Jakub there is no mention of any failing wrt to GPS into your question. The stacktrace is entirely due to incorrect config of your layout and code. It would have happened regardless of whether your are even using GPS.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment called AdFragment in it's createView () method you inflate wrong layout you must inflate fragment with layout contains com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
And you named it AdFragment xml

Answer (score 0):

I think William had it right as it was what worked for me in the end:

- Ensure your fragments extend 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
- Ensure your main activity extends 'FragmentActivity' rather than just 'Activity'

Answer (score -1):

This error is due to `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xx.activities.MainActivity$AdFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment` Change your fragment_ad.xml to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--ads:adUnitId sets the ad unit ID, which is defined in values/strings.xml -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And please see the full project source code. [googleads-mobile-android-examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/BannerExample/app)

I can't add new comment Please post your layouts with it's names and your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Please show edit. Yes as I mentioned, I followed the google's hints. This xml is the same.

Comment: How about "google_play_services_version" version, the "4030500" is ok ? How about the placeholder, can we omit this?

Comment: hema18, please give me the significant difference between those fragment_ad.xml I've posted at the beginning.